# How to autocomplete words with spaces in between in an edittext

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, multiautocompletetextview

I am trying to make a code editor for various programming languages but I am unable to add autocomplete feature to it.

I tried to use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` but it takes `,` as the default separator between words.

For reference I want to make an app like ACODE

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your code:

```
    yourmultiAutoCompletetextViewname.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());
```

This will make space as a seperator between two words.